# The norm of a bounded linear operator has this formula: $\|T\| = \sup_{\|v\| = 1} \|T v\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Trying to prove $\|T\| = \sup_{\|v\| = 1} \|T v\|$, given $\|T\| := \inf_{C \geq 0} \{C: \|Tv\| \leq C\|v\|\}$.

I know that $\|T(v)\| = \|T(\alpha \hat{v})\| \leq C\|\alpha \hat{v}\|$ for $v = \alpha \hat{v}$, with $\hat{v}$ some unit vector, so we have that if $\|T(v)\| \leq C\|v\|$, then $\|T(\hat{v})\| \leq C$.  By that we have $\sup_{\|v\| = 1} \|T(v)\| \leq \|T\|$.  To get equality, if $\|T \| \gt \sup_{\|v\| = 1}\|T(v)\|$ ... now what?

Comment: Hint: Let $w\ne 0$. Then, $\| Tw \| = \|Tv \| \|w\|$ with $v=w/\|w\|$. Thus, $\|Tw\| \le \sup_{\|v\|=1} \|Tv\| \|w\|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the other direction, if $v \neq 0$, then $||Tv|| =  ||v|| \cdot||T( \frac{v}{||v||})|| \le ||v|| \cdot \sup_{||v|| = 1} ||Tv||$.

So, $||T|| \le \sup_{||v|| = 1} ||Tv||$

Comment: Can you edit this into your first answer instead of posting it as two answers??

Answer (score 0):

$||T|| := \inf\limits_{C \geq 0} \{ C: ||Tv|| \leq C||v||, \ \forall v \in V\} = \inf\limits_{C\geq 0}\{C: ||Tv|| \leq C, \forall ||v|| = 1\}$.  We established the last equality in comments made above.  So if $||T|| \gt \sup\limits_{||v|| = 1} ||Tv||$, then there exists $||Tv|| \gt \sup\limits_{||v|| = 1} ||Tv||$ with $||v|| = 1$, impossible!